# how to pass a value to a data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I pass one `data-attribute` value to another?

I have the following input:

```
<input type="radio" class="d-none" name="varieties" value="option_0" data-price-package-value-id-0="2 625">
```

Where I need to transfer the value of `data-price-package-value-id-0` to the following element:

```
<li id="front_0" data-value="1 625">
```

[Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP9VW.png)

Here's the JavaScript I have so far:

```
// Radio buttons prise
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="varieties"]:checked').change(function() {
        var package_select = this.attr('data-price-package-value-id-0');

        var dataval = document.getElementById("0").attr('data-value');
        dataval = package_select;
    });
});
```

I also have a range input that already pulls the value out of li this already works but in another function,

now I have a task to pass the value from radio to li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should probably not be using ID's that start with a number, as it makes it harder to select in CSS and jQuery, but here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="varieties"]').change(function() {
        var package_select = $(this).attr('data-price-package-value-id-0');
        $(document.getElementById("0")).attr('data-value', package_select );
    });
});
```

Comment: I have several input radio when I click on which the value in li should change

Comment: I need to store this data in the attributes, perhaps you know another solution?

Comment: Can you post the page you're attempting this on, or at least more markup? This code should work, but I'd need the actual HTML of the other `radio`s and `li`s to get it working.

Comment: The picture doesn't quite give me enough to go on, but I edited my answer. is the attribute of all the radios "data-price-package-value-id-0"?

Comment: yes, all radios have this attribute
<input type="radio" class="d-none" name="varieties" value="option_0" data-price-package-value-id-0="2 625"
data-price-package-value-id-2="10950">

<input type="radio" class="d-none" name="varieties" value="option_0" data-price-package-value-id-0="1 625"
data-price-package-value-id-2="6950">

<ul id="order_range_options">
    <li id="front_0" data-value="1 625" class="transition option_left active" value="">1 – 1,9 м</li>
    <li id="front_2" data-value="6 950" class="transition option_right">2 – 3 м</li>
</ul>

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet - He had Javascript originally in the question if you check the edit logs, but he edited it out and I forgot to edit it back in..

Answer (score 0):

`attr()` is a jQuery method.  If you want to do this with vanilla javascript, then you will want to use

```
this.getAttribute('data-price-package-value-id-0')
this.setAttribute('data-price-package-value-id-0', newValue)
```

If you want to use jQuery then use

```
$(this).data('price-package-value-id-0') //getter
$(this).data('price-package-value-id-0', newValue) //setter
```

Or you can use `attr()` but do not intermix the use of `attr()` and `data()`

```
$(this).attr('data-price-package-value-id-0') //getter
$(this).attr('data-price-package-value-id-0', newValue) //setter
```

Answer (score 0):

`const element = document.getElementById('front_0');
element.setAttribute('data-value', 'my spectacular new value');`